# How to show/select Quote Of The Day

Tags: php, refresh

I have a database with lots of quote's and I want to create a `"Quote of the Day"` page.
The basic idea is to fetch all the quotes from the database, place this in an array and echo the quote at a random index number in the array.

That is the basic idea which is very to implement and which I have of course covered so far.
The problem is, every time the page is refreshed, a new quote will pop up.
This is not what I want.

I want the page to **refresh the quote** ONLY at `0:00` (*or another time, but that is not the point*).

Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should all users see the same quote?

Comment: and how many quotes do you have in your database? will the number change (grow) or will it stay the same?

Comment: configure the cron job see the link [http://docs.phplist.com/CronJobExamples.html] and [http://www.thefactory.ro/php-cron-tutorial]

Comment: @Chris It is best to assume it will grow, there is no point making code that is needlessly hard to adapt to new additions.

Comment: @bearbin: yes, agree partially. Just, if user1390504 wants to show one different quote each day, we may assume that i won't grow to 10.000 of quotes, or if it did, it might be a different approach than if it was just some hundred. Furthermore, if it grows as fast or faster as time (so each day 1 new quote or more), the approach might be different too.

Comment: one more question: is the change of quotes randomly? E.g. day1: quote2, day2:quote4, day3:quote1, day4:quote2, day5:quote3? Or is it day1:quote1, day2:quote2, day3:quote3, ... day1:quote1, ...?

Comment: I have a website, where one can enter a quote; so that the quote will be stored in the database. I would like to add a quote of the day to this site, and I would like to design the quote of the day non-hardcoded, in a way such that new quotes will automatically be a possible quote aswell.

Currentelly I fetch ALL the quotes and choose a random one, which I echo. I would like this to remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds overly complex. The normal way to do something like this would be

- Store the quotes in the database; give each row a date
- On every request, fetch the quote of the current day from the database and display it.

If you don't want to specify a date in the database, you could also hard-code a start date in your script (like, say, today's date) and then fetch the quote accordingly - so today, you'd fetch the first row in your database; tomorrow, the second, and so on.

Comment: Actually, it is NOT so complex if you have a look at the concept proposed [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11924019/1548719).

Comment: @Paul that's a nice method, too

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that this method is the most elegant and requires less programming achieving same (_required_) result. Logic is reduced to elementary functions and requires less effort to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Your final code should look something like this where each quote in your database has the "day" field as the day (0-365) that it should display on.

```
<?php
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `quotes` WHERE `day` = ?");
$query->execute(date("z", strtotime("today")));

$row = $query->fetch();
echo $row['quote'];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the date as the RNG seed, that way it will update each day :)

Here is some code:

```
mt_srand(date('dmY')); //Sets mt_rand seed to date.
$displayno = mt_rand(0, $total_quotes); //Generates random number with that seed, and the amount of quotes.
display_quote($displayno); //Pre-defined function that gets quote from database, and displays it.
```

Edit: This worked perfectly when i tested it. (http://pi.berboe.co.uk/stacks.php is a working example, it chooses a random number between 0 and 200 once every day.)

This assumes $total_quotes is set earlier, and is the amount of entries in the quote database.

Comment: @Petra Random Number generator, what you use to get a random quote.

Comment: @Petra Let me explain, mt_srand(date('dmY')) sets the 'seed' of the random number generator, you can set it and it will make mt_rand (0, $total_quotes) output the same number for the rest of the day, as date('dmY') outputs the date, month and year.

Answer (score 3):

This is not as easy as it seems on the first sight, maybe.

Let's say you have 365 quotes and this number will not change - easy, you could use 1 for each day. So, you just need an algorithm that gives you the number of the day in the year and this will be the id of the row you pull out of the database. E.g. February, 1st is the 32 day in the database -> go for that quote.

Let's say you have 2000 quotes and the number might change -> how will you handle that? What is your approach? Is it allowed to show a quote twice a year? How will all the quotes be shown if you have more than 365?

UPDATE:

```
//get number of quotes from DB
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM quotes

$day_in_year=date('z')+1; //-> this will give you the number of days in a year, for today
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

First of all I assume you can get number of quotes in the database, I'll refer to it as `number_of_quotes`.

Then you can use something like `PHP` `microtime()` function to get the `os timestamp` and divide it by

```
(1000 /* for converting microseconds to milliseconds */ * 
1000 /* milliseconds to seconds */ * 
3600 /* seconds to hours */ * 
24 /* hours to days */)
```

to get the number of days passed until now, I'll refer to this as `number_of_days_passed`.

Finally you can fetch `number_of_days_passed % (number_of_quotes + 1)`th row from your quotes table.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution is to `mark` already shown quotes. This way you should decide only how to select one and the same quote during the day.

`Next` quote can be selected randomly in the beginning of the day and marked as `todays` quote. This task can be performed using `CRON` and you will need only to select quote marked as `todays` (during the day).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers. The answer I was looking for, was not given unfortunatelly.

This is how I eliminated the problem:

I created a new table, called quote.

It had 1 row: the date on which the last quote of the day was updated and the quote itsself.
When the date did not match the server date, I generated a new quote and updated the table with the new quote and new date. If it did match the current date, it fetched the quote and displayed it.

Fairly easy solution, but it was very out of the box for me.

Answer (score 1):

Get today 00:00 unix time and store it as $variable in your code.

```
$id = (time() - $variable) % (24 * 60 * 60);
"SELECT * FROM `quotes` WHERE `id` = {$id}"
```

Comment: 24 * 60 * 60 is amount of seconds in 24h. You better do calculations with 86400 rather than with 24 * 60 * 60 :)